# How to convert string to date format?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-date

Hi any one please help me...

The below mentioned line is one column data.

```
column1:Supplier Setup request submitted on 2016-01-06 06:00:25.141 by WFS ADMINISTRATOR
```

I want to divide into two columns like `columnA` and `columnB`:

```
columnA                   columnB
WFS ADMINISTRATOR        2016-01-06 06:00:25.141
```

I wrote query by using sub string and instring functions:

```
select SUBSTR(column1, INSTR(column1,'on',1)+2, INSTR(column1,'by',1)-INSTR(column1,'on',2)-2) as columnB
from xyz
```

It is working fine, but I want to display date format like `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`.

I can't able to get date format...

Comment: Tag dbms used! (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: @bharathi I added the Oracle tag for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the datetime part with

```
regexp_replace(col, '.*on (.*) by.*', '\1')
```

You convert such string to timestamp with

```
to_timestamp(str, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
```

And you convert a timestamp to a string formatted `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` with

```
to_char(ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Together:

```
to_char
(
  to_timestamp
  (
    regexp_replace(col, '.*on (.*) by.*', '\1'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'
  ), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
)
```

Comment: Hi,the above query is working.But that column contains as below shown
converted_on
---------------------
 2016-01-06 06:00:25.141 
 2015-12-28 19:50:23.98 
 2015-10-19 00:09:37.314 
 04/22/2013 16:43:08 
by using your query it converted 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff' to 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'.
but not converting for 'mm-yyyy-hh24:mi:ss.ff' to 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'.
it throws error like as
**oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month**

Comment: Are you saying that your date strings differ? So while one string contains '2016-01-06 06:00:25.141', another contains '04/22/2013 16:43:08'? Maybe even more formats? You can deal with that with CASE expressions (e.g. if a dash in in position 5 it is the ANSI format, if a slash is in position 3 it is MM/DD... etc.). You can do this in two steps: Separate the string in a derived table (subquery), then select from this to to the evaluation.

Comment: But maybe you'd prefer to write a PL/SQL function for this. SQL is not really made for things like these, and a programming language like PL/SQL may be more convenient. You could even use try and fail methods (trying to convert with one format, catch the exception, try another format, ...).

Answer (score 0):

assuming that columnB now hold the date part:

```
to_date(columnB,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Thanks,
 I have used to_date function but getting this error
**oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month**
query is
    select to_date(SUBSTR(column1,INSTR(column1,'on',1)+2,INSTR(column1,'by',1)-INSTR(column1,'on',2)-2),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as columnB from xyz

Comment: is columnB data type set as 'DATE'?

Comment: Try changing it to     to_date(columnB, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: please help me how to convert

Comment: i changed but still getting error as **oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string**
   select to_date(SUBSTR(column1,INSTR(column1,'on',1)+2,INSTR(column1,'by',1)-INSTR(colum‌​n1,'on',2)-2),'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') as columnB from xyz